# Request and response Queue in Apache XML RPC server

Tags: xml, queue, rpc

i developed a XML RPC server by using Apache XMLRPC API , RPC Server takes client request to perform some operations on other servers, and send back response to client , RPC server have some connections to other server which are non serialize and not thread safe ,

if more than one client request comes to RPC server ,it is not possible to fulfill are request request at same time due to connections to other server are not thread safe and non serialize ,

i want to add a  request queue and response queue to XML RPC server , so we can perform operations of each client request how it can be done,

How i can add functionality of request and response queue .